# Unable to set mvn JAVA_HOME setting

Tags: java, maven

```
ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  96 Jun 15 14:30 jdk-11.0.7.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  96 Jul 15 16:59 jdk1.8.0_261.jdk

# Tell maven to use explicit jdk
$ JAVA_HOME=`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/` mvn -version

# Despite explicitly setting JAVA_HOME, mvn is still using JDK11
-bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/: is a directory
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.7.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I've also tried setting JAVA_HOME manually with:
`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home`

for some reason mvn insists on using jdk 11. Do you know where it might be overridden?

My pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mvn-compiler.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
      <debug>true</debug>
      <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME exporting command is incorrect.

Your bash message also saying the same thing. You used back tick you need to use single quote or double quote

Correct statement would be

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/ mvn --version
```